# How to use webpack with extract-text-webpack-plugin to compile scss files to css

Tags: webpack, sass, angular-material2, extracttextwebpackplugin

I have created an angular2 project with angular material2 components. Now I want to customise my theme so I have used `webpack` module as this will create one single file from all the scss files so I have  used `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to create individual files.

Here is my **webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
// multiple extract instances
let extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        '/src/assets/theme/'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.scss$/i, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css', 'sass']) }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS
    ]
}
```

And here is the script in my package.json

```
"build:css": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
```

and the command to run

```
npm run build:css
```

but this is showing

```
> webpack --config webpack.config.js

Hash: a5e945c400552ce5350f
Version: webpack 3.3.0
Time: 68ms
   Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  2.6 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi /src/assets/theme/ 28 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in multi /src/assets/theme/
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/src/assets/theme/' in 'D:\Workspace\WebAdmin_Blade_Template_Material2\webapp'
 @ multi /src/assets/theme/

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build:css"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! webapp@1.0.0 build:css: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webapp@1.0.0 build:css script 'webpack --config webpack.config.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the webapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack --config webpack.config.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs webapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls webapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Problem is with the `entry`, but not able to solve this? what is the issue? Am I missing something?

**Edited**

I was missing **index.js** in src/assets/theme/. Here is the content of this file

```
require('./theme.scss');
require('./custom.scss');
```

and installed `css-loader` and `sass-loader`.

To make this working changed

```
loaders: [
                { test: /\.scss$/i, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css', 'sass']) }
            ]
```

instead of CSS and sass to css-loader and sass-loader.

the problem is, it is creating one single file from all the sccss files in /dist/main.css file. How can I create individiual files for each scss file?

Comment: why don't you use  entry : [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assests/theme')] instead ?

Comment: @DebabrataMohanta still the same error : Module not found. but in this folder there is no module just my theme.scss file

Comment: I am assuming theme is the file name theme.scss  if so you need to give the extension as well bcoz by default it looks for .js so use theme.scss instead.

Comment: @DebabrataMohanta , check updated question